# Create XHTML pages dynamically?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, richfaces

Is it possible to dynamically create PrimeFaces or RichFaces pages?
What I want to do is build up an editor in a kind of "members" area within my application, where the users can create forms by selecting multiple check boxes, radio buttons, text boxes, and place them at defined positions.
I would think the information of such a dynamic page would best be stored in the database.
Are there ready to use functions that provide dynamic page creation like this?
Or do I have to build it myself using loops and switches?
I kindly thank in advance for any help on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it either declaratively (switches in the xhtml to show or not certain components) or programmatically, adding new components to the UI root. Use FacesContext to obtain the UI root and then add the classes you need. (for example, you might add a InputText object).